# Using Tikz arrow shapes in math mode of a article or book

Tags: math-mode, tikz-arrows

I want to change the arrow in the math mode, `\to`, into the arrow shape drawn by the `tikz` package. In fact, when I want to use `\to`, I want to replace the  following arrow

[image]

with

[image]

The arrows plotted by `tikz`, as all of you know, may be obtained from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,arrows,matrix,shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 1.5cm,
arrow/.style={
  -latex',
 shorten >= 3pt,
  shorten <= 3pt,
}
]

\draw[arrow]
  (0,0) -- (1,0);        
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It is obvious that the length of the arrow is not important and it may change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\let\oldto\to
\renewcommand\to[1][1.4em]{\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex, 
                                 shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt] \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (#1,0);}
\begin{document}
$a\to b$

$a \oldto b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not so simple. Try

```
\[a  \to b c_{x\to y_{z \to 0}}\]
```

My proposal is to use the `picture` mode arrow as [suggested by @LSGQ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/571058/38080) but using `\matchoice` to adapt the size, and using `\mathop` to obtain the correct spacing; clearly if you prefer Ti*k*Z arrows you can adapt [@Zarko's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/571057/38080) as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\originalto\to
\newcommand{\sizedarrow}[2]{\raisebox{#2ex}{\scalebox{#1}{\vector(1,0){1em}}}}
\newcommand{\arrowto}{\mathchoice
    {\sizedarrow{1}{0.5}}%
    {\sizedarrow{0.8}{0.4}}%
    {\sizedarrow{0.6}{0.35}}%
    {\sizedarrow{0.5}{0.3}}%
}
\renewcommand{\to}{\mathop{\arrowto}}
\begin{document}
\[a \originalto b  c_{x\originalto y_{z\originalto 0}}\]
\[a  \to b c_{x\to y_{z \to 0}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you only need horizontal arrows, you don't need to load any packages, base LaTeX is enough:

```
\renewcommand{\to}{\raisebox{.5ex}{\ \vector(1,0){.5cm}\ }}
```

(in fact, is good old `pict` package). You can adjust length and math spacing. Works in math mode.