# How to create a new `\to` or `\rightarrow` symbol with a black head?

Tags: symbols, arrows

How to create a new `\to` or `\rightarrow` symbol with a black head as the left side of the following picture?

[image]

Similarly, I'd like to get the `\leftarrow`, `\leftrightarrow`, and the negation of them, of this kind. By the way it's better that

1. they should adapt the font sizes;
2. the spacings before and after them are suitable.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571055/using-tikz-arrow-shapes-in-math-mode-of-a-article-or-book ?

Comment: You can try the `mathabx` package. (Do you mean "head" and not "tail"?)

Comment: The heads of arrows in mathabx seems to be not black enough as in the picture.

Comment: Hope this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602080/use-a-latex-length-for-an-arrow-head-length-in-tikz might helps you (refer `egreg` suggestion)

Comment: @Rmano and MadyYuvi  Thanks! While it seems that they are not exactly as what I asked.

Comment: `Michael Barr`s old supporting file `diagxy.tex` redefines the tag `\to` you can download it from `CTAN`

Answer (score 2):

The [pdfMsym](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfmsym?lang=en) package offers some tools for defining arrows. Their size should be compatible with your font size, and they scale with sub/superscripts. It also will create longer and extendable variants of the arrows. The package is intended for plain TeX, but it works with LaTeX as well.

[image: arrow example]

```tex
\input pdfmsym

\pdfmsymsetscalefactor{10}  % Your current font size

\catcode`@=11

\def\@rstraightarrow{\@linehead@type{0 0 m 2 0 l S 2 0 m 0 1.25 l 1 0 l 0 -1.25 l 2 0 l b}{2}}
\def\@lstraightarrow{\@linehead@type{2 0 m 0 0 l S 0 0 m 2 1.25 l 1 0 l 2 -1.25 l 0 0 l b}{2}}

\@arrow@def{rsarrow}\@linecap\@rstraightarrow
\@arrow@def{lsarrow}\@lstraightarrow\@linecap
\@arrow@def{lrsarrow}\@lstraightarrow\@rstraightarrow

\catcode`@=12

$$ A\rsarrow B $$
$$ A\lsarrow B $$
$$ A\lrsarrow B $$

\bye
```

Explanations of the pdfMsym macros used can be found in its documentation, page 14.

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill, but you can design your own arrow with Ti*k*Z.

[image]

Here is a modified `stealth` arrowtip. The command is `\myarrow`, which can take `tikz` options. For example, `\myarrow[->]` or `\myarrow[<-]` or `\myarrow[<->]`. Other options include `[>-]` and `[>->].`

You can also add the option `not`, as well as other `tikz` options such as color, line thickness and style (`dotted`, `dashed`, etc.). You can use `scale=` to change the length.

Note that these arrows will not adjust size for subscripts, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.markings}

\tikzset{not/.style={postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position .5 with {\draw[-] (-1pt,-2pt) -- (1pt,2pt);}}}}}

\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][]{\mathrel{\tikz[baseline=-.5ex]{
    \draw[line cap=round, >={Stealth[round, length=4pt, width=4pt]}, #1](0,0)--(.3351,0);
}}}

\begin{document}

$A\myarrow[->]B\myarrow[<-]C\myarrow[<->]D$

$A\to B\leftarrow C\leftrightarrow D$

$A\myarrow[->,not]B\myarrow[<-,not]C\myarrow[<->,not]D$

\end{document}
```