# A problem in creating symbols by TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

First, a minimal working sample is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\newcirc{\mathrel{%
\tikz{%
\draw (0em,0em) circle [radius=0.2em];%
}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\phi\newcirc\psi
\]

\end{document}
```

As you see, I defined a math symbol of `\newcirc` by `TikZ`. It seems to work well.  While when I put it in the script without brackets, for example, `$\phi_\newcirc$`, it doesn't work. So is there any way to fix the problem by revising the codes? (I don't like to add brackets every time when I use it singly in the script, for example, `$\phi_{\newcirc}$`)

Comment: If you add more than one character to the subscript, you have to use curly brackets. So `$\phi_{\newcirc}$` is correct. But you can put `\bgroup` and `\egroup` (or a pair of curly brackets) intro the command to make it work for the command.

Comment: See [Why do I have to put braces around my macro for subscripts / indices? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/556915/why-do-i-have-to-put-braces-around-my-macro-for-subscripts-indices) and related questions.

Comment: @dexteritas While in this way, the spacing around the symbol would change.

Comment: Ok, yes, if you put brackets around `\mathrel` the spacing usually added by this is ignored, so `$\phi_{\newcirc}$` would be the best way, to not change the behavior in the other case.

Comment: I agree that the correct way is to get used to use `_{...}` (which is the correct, LaTeX syntax anyway). You can get a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/571062/38080 for a way to make the symbols scale.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but your symbol will not scale down when used in a subscript. You might consider the `scalerel` package and the definition `\newcommand{\newcirc}{\mathrel{\scalerel*{\tikz{\draw circle [radius=0.2em];}}{x}}}`.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't like to add brackets every time when I use it singly in the script, for example, `$\phi_{\newcirc}$`

You may define a command which frees you from typing `_{ }`:

```
\newcommand{\phiI}[1]{\phi_{#1}}
\phiI\newcirc
```

which works as long as you your intention i to put just one token after `\phiI`.

(It is good idea to combine that with scaled definition of `\newcirc`  as Rmano suggests.)

---

You could define `_` to make it behave the same as `\ind` I define bellow, but I do not think redefining `_` is a good idea.

---

There are more ways how to save some typing:

```
\newcommand\phicirc{\phi_{\newcirc}}
\[ \phicirc \]

\newcommand\gr[1]{{#1}}
\[ \phi_\gr\newcirc \]

\newcommand\grcirc{{\newcirc}}
\[ \phi_\grcirc \]


\newcommand\ind[1]{_{#1}}
\[ \phi\ind\newcirc \]

\newcommand\indcirc{_{\newcirc}}
\[ \phi\indcirc \]
\[ \psi\indcirc - \mu\indcirc\]

\newcommand\withcirc[1]{#1_{\newcirc}}
\[ \withcirc\psi + \withcirc\mu + \withcirc\phi  \]
```

---

Sometimes I use optional arguments, e.g.,

```
\renewcommand\phicirc[1][]{\phi_{\newcirc#1}}
\[ \phicirc  \qquad   \phicirc[_3]   \]
```

Comment: But we may use $\psi_{\newcirc}$ and so on.

Comment: You can use any choice of the suggestion. For example `\mu\indcirc` or define `\mucirc` analogically to `\phicirc`. Or we can define `\withcirc` -- I will added it to the answer.

Comment: It seems not to decrease the consumption of physical power validly.

Comment: @M.Logic Do you mean it doesn't reduce the typing?